# How to insert rows into a mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to write a script to be used an automated test to constantly insert rows into a mysql db.  Which scripting language is best suited for this?

I'm using php to read the db and create html.  Does it makes sense to use PHP for this too? Or would I be better off using ruby, or some other mechanism?

Comment: Stick with what you know, use PHP.

Comment: how should i execute the php.  right now, i only use php to generate html.  is there a more generic command line use of it. (sorry just started php on sunday). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Learn how to use MySql Stored Procedures.](http://mysqlstoredprocedure.com/) And AFAIK, **PHP** was built to generate HTML from start. Any *noticeable* performance problems should *probably* arise from your knowledge of html.

Comment: this is helpful in general but it doesn't answer the question. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpadmin, toad, or any other MySql IDE to run the script:

```
BEGIN
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like i should just use php from cmd line, which is apparently possible.